# GKI exception when BLe write characteristic for 10K bytes on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am implement Bluetooth low energy function on Android platform.
My target is sending about 10k bytes data to target device,
I list down my step as below:

step 1 : split data to multi-packet with 20bytes.

step 2 : run function  `characteristic.setValue(data) / gatt. writeCharacteristic()`

step 3 : wait for `onCharacteristicWrite()`

step 4 : After `onCharacteristicWrite()` , `gatt.writeCharacteristic(next data)`

loop step3 until all datas are send.

I run this application on Nexus 6, LG G3, Infocus M320. Its all workable.

But when I run the same Application on ASUS phone/pad, is will occur GKI exception(out of buffers) in few seconds.

Is their any method to solve this issue?

Until now, I only found this issue on ASUS phone/pad.

Thanks,

Comment: I slow down the transfer speed, and it never occur the error.